# Trouble With GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am having trouble with `GridBagLayout`.

A user selects a file, and if that file is bigger than the `JTextArea` that I display it in, all the Swing components in the shared `GridBagLayout` go haywire. If it is able to fit in the `JTextField`, all the Swing components are fine.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wMuW.png) of the `JFrame` layout I desire:

[image: Want]

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU88R.png) is the `JFrame` layout I get when the `JTextArea` containing the file path is bigger than its allotted size.

[image: Have]

All the other `JTextFields` are affected as well as the buttons below. I don't care if the text in the `JTextArea` is bigger than its size, I just want all the swing components to stay the same.

Here is the code where I add the Swing components into the File info panel:

```
    //Setup layout.
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //File info panel.
    gbc.insets = new Insets(3, 10, 3, 10);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    info_panel.add(first_name_jta, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    info_panel.add(first_name_tf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    info_panel.add(last_name_jta, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    info_panel.add(last_name_tf, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    info_panel.add(frame_type_jta, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    info_panel.add(frame_type_cb, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    info_panel.add(eye_size_jta, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    info_panel.add(eye_size_tf, gbc);

    //Frame panel.
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    frame_panel.add(file_path_tf, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    frame_panel.add(info_panel, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 60, 10, 60);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    frame_panel.add(save_button, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    frame_panel.add(cancel_button, gbc);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that took a bit of effort.

Basically, when you build the `frame_panel`, you use `gridwidth = 2` for the `file_path_tf` and `info_panel`, which is all fine an good, but you never reset the attribute when you add the buttons.

This means that `save_button` can occupy columns 0 and 1 and `cancel_button` can occupy 1 and 2

Reset the `gridwidth` attribute after you've added the `info_pane` and before you add the buttons

```
gbc.gridwidth = 1;
```

Also, I think you'll find `JLabel`s much easier to deal with then `JTextArea`s for labeling fields, but that's just me.

Comment: The file path is a `JTextField`. Everything shrinks when the JTextField has a bigger value. When it has a smaller value, every component is set to its default size.

Comment: Can you supply a runnable example, your code is tripping me out ;)

Comment: I reconstructed your code example into a runnable example as best as I could and updated the answer

Comment: Awesome. I love you. I'll switch them to JLabels too. Any way to not have the `GridBagLayout`'s column dimensions be determined by the size of the text entered where the file path is?

Comment: Technically not really.  The `JTextField`, especially in this case, will try and expand to fill the available space. You could try adding the buttons to there own panel, using a single column for all three components (file field, info panel and button panel).  This will at least stop the buttons from reacting to the change in the field...